# linq query "must be reducible node" error in Asp.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have following query which doesn't work with "must be reducible node" error.
It seems that translation to SQL code doesn't work properly.
I tired using DbFunctions.CreateDateTime but it gives exactly same result.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
            var query = from i in _context.Schedule
                        group i by new { i.Date.Month, i.Date.Year } into g
                        where new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1) >= eDate
                        select g.Key;
```

Comment: Have you isolated it to the _where clause_?

Comment: It might help to post the exact .Net version, as there were some bugs in some of them causing this error.

Comment: @Yeronimo Sorry, forgot about versions, I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.1
Flydog57 Yes, it happens when I'm using "new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1)" statement. If I change it for example to "new DateTime()" it works, but this is not what I need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are using Core which has limitations.  Try following :

```
var query = _context.Schedule.Where(g => new DateTime(g.Year, g.Month, 1) >= eDate)
     .GroupBy(i => new { i.Date.Month, i.Date.Year })
     .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Yes, this one looks like working, I will confirm tomorrow once I test everything. Thank you! 
I would like to know more about limitation though. I'm using Asp.Net Core MVC 2.1
Also what is particular difference between request you typed and mine? I thought that using linq is more convinient way of expressing SQL queries in EF...
P.S. I'm newbie so don't blame if I ask silly questions :)

Comment: The Core library is much smaller than the Net library so it will fit into mobile applications.

Comment: @Wadim Your query used the group by `Key` for the `where` - if you had put the `where` before the group by and tested against `i` it should be equivalent to this.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I changed my linq statement as proposed and it worked.